# Why Can I not access this ASP Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using a Telerik RadGrid and using an EditItemTemplate as shown in my ASP code below.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn" HeaderText="Role">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Role") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" UniqueName="Roles"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn
```

I am attempting to populate the dropdown using Entity Framework with this C# code:

```
protected void gvMembers_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var roles = (from c in DbContext.roles
                     select new { c.Role1, c.RoleID }).ToList();
        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

        //// access/modify the edit item template settings here
        DropDownList list = item.FindControl("Roles") as DropDownList;
        list.DataTextField = "Role1";
        list.DataValueField = "RoleID";
        list.DataBind();

    }
```

I am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Since I am relatively new to programming I am stumped by this error message it appears to me I am not able to find that Roles control.  I have attempted to use the Control ID put get the same results. I have spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem so any help with this would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: @EmptyWaterHoles I get the error message on the line That begins with DropDownList

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you have got as the sender to this method.
But for example if it was a button you could replace this line

```
GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
```

with this line

```
Button item = (Button) sender;
```

and this line

```
DropDownList list = item.FindControl("Roles") as DropDownList;
```

with this line

```
DropDownList list = item.NamingContainer.FindControl("Roles") as DropDownList;
```

because `item` is null you can not use it  with .FindControl

Replace Button with what ever is calling the method

Comment: the sender is the ItemDataBound it fires as the giridview is being rendered.  I changed the code to what you recommended but got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue.  The problem was the code was being run at the wrong time.  I was attempting to access a control in the EditItemTemplate which is only available when the item is in editmode.  After changing my code to check the mode it now works.  Here is the corrected code

```
protected void gvMembers_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            var roles = (from c in DbContext.roles
                         select new { c.Role1, c.RoleID }).ToList();
            GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            // access/modify the edit item template settings here
            DropDownList list = item.FindControl("List1") as DropDownList;
            list.DataSource = roles;
            list.DataBind();
        }

    }
```